# Concatenate 2D numpy array with an empty array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

This Python 3.8 code snippet:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6]])
a = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
print(a)
```

produces:

```
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [5 6]]
```

as expected. How do I define an empty array `e`, such that this code produces the same result:

```
# define en empty array e here
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6]])
e = np.concatenate((e, a), axis=0)
e = np.concatenate((e, b), axis=0)
print(e)
```

The use case here is an algorithm, which starts with an empty array and concatenates additional arrays to it in a loop.

Comment: Why not `e = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenating empty array in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732589/concatenating-empty-array-in-numpy)

Comment: @DaniMesejo I have to start with an empty array for brevity and elegance.

Comment: Elegance is in the eye of the beholder... and the answer posted is for sure not more breve (in terms of LOC) that the one in the question.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Yes, `np.array([], shape=(0, 5), dtype=int64)` would work too. I answered with a slightly different option.

Comment: @DaniMesejo Obviously not an elegance of the snippet I posted. Brevity of an algorithm, which assumes an empty array at the beginning.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh, the answers in that 2014 link are mostly unsatisfactory.  While it is possible to create an initial array with an appropriate 0 dimension, it's more efficient to build a list of arrays, and do just one `concatenate` at the end.

Comment: @hpaulj op wanted to do it in this way, I provided an answer that does it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
e = np.empty((0, 2))
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6]])
e = np.concatenate((e, a), axis=0)
e = np.concatenate((e, b), axis=0)
print(e)
```

Comment: better yet `f = np.concatenate((e,a,b), axis=0)`.  One concatenate on the full list is better  than repeated ones.  Less copying.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook you for a beginner who didn't realize that list append is more efficient than repeated `np.concatenate`.  List append works in-place, and just adds a reference.  `concatenate` makes a new array each time, with all the copying that entails.  So yes, if you want to concatenate  a "empty" array it needs to have the same number of dimensions as the others, here `(0,2), (2,2) , (1,2)`.  Calling `np.empty((0,2))` "empty" is a bit of a misnomer.  It shouldn't be confused with the list `[]`.

Comment: Watch the `dtype` with this code.  `e` is a float, `a` is int.  Conditional code that sets `e=a` on the first iteration may be safer, and a bit faster (one less concatenate), even it it isn't as pretty.